# How to convert integer array to list using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I had a dataframe column like as shown below

```
col1
<NA>
123.23
453.21
567.21
879.21
```

To convert float with NaN into integer, I did the below

```
df['col1'].astype(float).astype('Int64')
```

When I do the below

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].fillna(0)
df['col1'].unique().tolist()
```

I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'IntegerArray' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

Comment: do `list(df['col1'].unique())`

Comment: that said, don't you have an error converting your floats to Int64?

Comment: If I use `astype` and then do `int`, I don't get any error

Comment: `df.col1.unique()` is already an array, there's not much point converting it to a list.

Comment: Tested and error `TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64`, if integers in input then for me working `print (list(df['col1'].unique()))`

Comment: Have you tried `df["col1"].fillna(0).astype(int).unique().tolist()` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = []
for i in df['col1']:
    i = int(i)
    nums.append(i)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: @Jeremy don't use this approach, looping through the elements and appending one by one is highly inefficient, and impractical. Plus, this doesn't get you the unique elements...